# How to include png image in between text of a label

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I want to ***include png image in between my text of a label.*** how to proceed with this in objective-c.

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318421/how-to-embed-small-icon-in-uilabel

Comment: thanx that has solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer in case someone find it useful----->

```
 NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Attach-52.png"];

    NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];

    NSMutableAttributedString *myString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My label text"];
    [myString appendAttributedString:attachmentString];

    myLabel.attributedText = myString;
```

Likewise you can add png image through NSAttributedString.