# How to make a bullet list with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So I want to make something like this using swift and xcode:

[image]

Where I get each dot from an array. What I have thought is to make a UILabel and make a for loop that iterates over the array and in each iteration it adds to the label \u{2022} + content. I know \u{2022} is the dot point in unicode, the problem is that I need a way to make the list divided in two columns as shown and to make the dot point color yellow. This cant be done if I add the dots programmatically as I described above because the default color would be black. As the number of dots varies from the array contents for example if the array is of size 3 then only 3 dots would show 2 in the left and one to the right I need a way to meet this requirement, the other method I thought was of having two table views that takes half the screen and add this elements to each table view depending on the array. What should be the best practice here or is there a way to make this in the storyboard in a form that is dependent of an array.

Comment: Might need to use CoreText for that , see the tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app)

Comment: Have you looked at UICollectionView? I haven't used it myself much, but this looks like a perfect use case for this.

Comment: So what you really want to know is how to draw text in two columns, and the bullet part is just a red herring, right?

Comment: "This cant be done if I add the dots programmatically as I described above because the default color would be black." Flapdoodle. Changing text color programmatically is easy.

Comment: @matt yeah thats somewhat the idea. Yes programmatically I can change the color of an entire text but not a part of it, this would imply that the dot and text should be two different labels and that would make the problem more complex.

Comment: No, you're wrong. An attributed string lets you color individual glyphs. In fact the whole thing could be done with a single view if you wanted.

Comment: @matt Well then that simplifies the problem to organizing the data in the two columns

Comment: That's right, and I've got an example that shows you how to do that. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p543drawingWithTextKit/ch23p815attributedStringDrawing3/StyledText.swift

Comment: Use collectionview or stackview with UILabel attributedString http://stackoverflow.com/a/42721312/7250862

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use 2 labels inside a view for the columns. both labels being multulined

```
class Helper {

    static func bulletedList(strings:[String], textColor:UIColor, font:UIFont, bulletColor:UIColor, bulletSize:BulletSize) -> NSAttributedString {
        let textAttributesDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName : font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textColor]

        let bulletAttributesDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName : font.withSize(bulletSize.rawValue), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:bulletColor]
        let fullAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init()

        for string: String in strings
        {
            let bulletPoint: String = "\u{2022}"
            let formattedString: String = "\(bulletPoint) \(string)\n"
            let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedString)
            let paragraphStyle = createParagraphAttribute()

            attributedString.addAttributes([NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
            attributedString.addAttributes(textAttributesDictionary, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

            let string:NSString = NSString(string: formattedString)
            let rangeForBullet:NSRange = string.range(of: bulletPoint)

            attributedString.addAttributes(bulletAttributesDictionary, range: rangeForBullet)
            fullAttributedString.append(attributedString)
        }
        return fullAttributedString
    }

    static func createParagraphAttribute() -> NSParagraphStyle {

        var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: 15, options: NSDictionary() as! [String : AnyObject])]
        paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = 15
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 3
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = 10
        return paragraphStyle
    }
}
```

and simply use `Helper.bulletedList` to create your bulletted list as Attributed text for the label

Answer (score 14):

I was not happy with the solutions above. So here is a Swifty function to get a bullet point list:

```
func bulletPointList(strings: [String]) -> NSAttributedString {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 15
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 22
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 22
    paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: 15)]

    let stringAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: regularSystem(size: 22),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
    ]

    let string = strings.map({ "•\t\($0)" }).joined(separator: "\n")

    return NSAttributedString(string: string,
                              attributes: stringAttributes)
}
```

And this is how you use it:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.attributedText = bulletPointList(strings: ["Foo", "Bar", "Lol"])
```

Comment: this is good for the list without changing bullet color. So it has same color as text and I was looking for this particular styling or else I could have just put the bullet in the text. and keep it simple.

Comment: Love it! ️
(these are more characters to enable comment posting)

Answer (score 10):

For Swift 5, you can use this class:

```
class NSAttributedStringHelper {
    static func createBulletedList(fromStringArray strings: [String], font: UIFont? = nil) -> NSAttributedString {

        let fullAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        let attributesDictionary: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
    
        if let font = font {
            attributesDictionary = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        } else {
            attributesDictionary = [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]()
        }
   
        for index in 0..<strings.count {
            let bulletPoint: String = "\u{2022}"
            var formattedString: String = "\(bulletPoint) \(strings[index])"
        
            if index < strings.count - 1 {
                formattedString = "\(formattedString)\n"
            }
        
            let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedString, attributes: attributesDictionary)
            let paragraphStyle = NSAttributedStringHelper.createParagraphAttribute()
   attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        fullAttributedString.append(attributedString)
       }
    
        return fullAttributedString
    }

    private static func createParagraphAttribute() -> NSParagraphStyle {
        let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: 15, options: NSDictionary() as! [NSTextTab.OptionKey : Any])]
        paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = 15
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = 11
        return paragraphStyle
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
let stringArray = ["first row", "second row", "third row"]
label.attributedText = NSAttributedStringHelper.createBulletedList(fromStringArray: stringArray, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15))
```

Comment: This solution is just perfect. Without much effort, it outputs the bullet list like in any good looking document. Thanks for sharing this code.

Comment: thanks for this cool snippet, one question, how could you put all the value in the center? I tried to do the text alignment in your helper class to center, but it didn't work, also my storyboard alignment is already set on center.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, the force cast while defining tab stops can be avoided.

`[NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: 15, options: [NSTextTab.OptionKey: Any]())]`

Also, we can use NSRange instead of NSMakeRange while adding the attributes.

    `NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)`

Answer (score 2):

In Swift tabStop will work with the following changes

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 0 // 0 means unlimited
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 0
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 30
paragraphStyle.headIndent = 0
paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: 15, options: Dictionary<NSTextTab.OptionKey, Any>())]
paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = 10  //changing defaultTabInterval changes the distance between black dot & text
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
```