# Determining the position of the end of the last line in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, label

The solution below works correctly only for names that fit on one line

```
        cell.accessoryTitleLabel.text = data.title
        cell.accessoryTitleLabel.sizeToFit()
        cell.discountIcon.frame.origin.x = cell.accessoryTitleLabel.frame.maxX + 7
        cell.discountIcon.hidden = discount == 0
```

But I need to put a discount icon at the end of the last line:
[image]

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318421/how-to-embed-small-icon-in-uilabel/42721312#42721312

Comment: Thanks for everyone. Can I change the alpha parameter for an attachment image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to **insert your image directly on label** by `NSTextAttachment` and **resizing the image as per requirement**, in that way you don't have to calculate any spacing and width.

---

Swift 3 solution

```
var img_attachment = NSTextAttachment()
img_attachment.image = UIImage(named: "name_of_image")
img_attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(ImgWidth), height:CGFloat(ImgHeight)) // you can specify the size and bounds of discount image
var attributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: img_attachment)
var lblString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "your text here")
lblString.append(attributedString)
cell.accessoryTitleLabel.attributedText = lblString
```

---

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can I change the alpha parameter for an attachment image?