# Xamarin.iOS add left image to UILable

Tags: xamarin.ios, uilabel

Here is my case I have custom control that inherent from UILable 
and I  need to create method that take image (from code or storyboard) 
to be added to my label

My tries to convert this code to Xamarin.iOS [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318421/how-to-embed-small-icon-in-uilabel)

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()        
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "yourIcon.png")
let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: price)
myString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
label.attributedText = myString


 public void SetLeftDrawable(UIImage image){

    var attachment = new NSTextAttachment();
    attachment.Image = image;
    var attachmentString = new 
    NSAttributedString(attachment,null);  // this method take string not NSTextAttachment 
  }
```

any one could help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void SetLeftDrawable (UIImage image)
{
    var attachment = new NSTextAttachment ();
    attachment.Image = image;
    var attachmentString = NSAttributedString.FromAttachment (attachment);
    //replace "price" with your string.
    var myString = new NSMutableAttributedString ("price");
    myString.Append (attachmentString);
    AttributedText = myString;
}
```

Hope this helps.-