# Putting UIImage in between UILabels text

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Currently I use this constraints to show user's notifications.

```
User Name.leading = User Image.trailing + 5
Status Image.leading = User Name.trailing + 2
Status Image.centerY = User Name.centerY
Notification Message.leading = Status Image.trailing + 3
Notification Message.trailing ≤ Notification Post.leading - 3
trailing = Notification Post.trailing + 5
```

And it gives me this result : [image]

But i want the Notification Message to align left when line count is bigger than 1. How can i achieve it ? Is it possible when I use 2 different UILabels for UserName and NotificationMessage ?
The actual UI positions I need to do is here: [image]

How can i achieve this? I would be grateful for any idea.

Comment: Look at `NSAttributedString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one label to achieve this.

- Append user name
- Add icon as [NSTextAttachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318421/how-to-embed-small-icon-in-uilabel)
- Append notification text