# Constraint follow last character of dynamic wrapping text label

Tags: swift

I am trying to have constraint so that a button (the green square in the figure) will be at the end of the last character of a neighbouring text label. I then want the button to be a set distance from the last character (".").

The text label has 0 rows so it should wrap to create new rows as needed but there will never be more than two rows.

The figure below explains by two examples. In the first example the text is so long that it wraps to a new row. So the green button goes past the right edge of the text label to get to where the dot it. In the second example the text fits into one row of the label and then the button will be placed right next to the text label.

[image: Example of green button constraint to text wrapping or not wrapping]

Is this even possible without writing very specific code that calculates depending on character count and replicating the dynamic row count?

Comment: What about using a image for that, adding an image to the end of the text with `NSAttributedString` & `NSTextAttachment`?

Comment: Your suggestion led me to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318421/how-to-embed-small-icon-in-uilabel which seems to be a possible solution. I will see if I can implement it to make it work as intended. Thank you!